# Can I use glyphicons in an android app?

Tags: android, glyphicons

Can I use [glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) in an android app?
If yes, how?

Comment: They are simply Images which can shown using `ImageView`...

Comment: You can use an iconic font (vectorial by definition) such as font awesome: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Comment: @DerGolem Is that convinient to use? Can I declare it in xml, I only know how to set it in code.

Comment: Like this: `android:text="This is an Android \uf17b"` (you have to set the TextView/Button/...font from assets, via Java code)

Comment: Check this library https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap/

Answer (score 2):

You can use ImageView to simply display a picture.

However Glyphicons icons are not free.
It's free for Twitter Bootstrap due to a partnership only.

If you want to display a SVG picture, take a look to this [article](http://blog.fordemobile.com/2013/01/display-svg-inside-imageview.html).

Comment: Is it efficient to use such graphics? Google must see a reason why the programmer should provide different resolutions of a Picture right?

Comment: It's efficient if you need to zoom on it, because, it's a vector graphic, you'll not see disgracious pixels but it's a little more complicated to render it. So I prefer to use standard icons (png/jpg) than vector graphics. You can find icon libraries such as https://www.iconfinder.com/ , http://iconsweets.com/ or some free projects on Dribble website.

Answer (score 0):

Allthough it is possible to use any custom image in an imageview it is not recomended by the [android branding guide](http://developer.android.com/design/style/branding.html), since the android user is familiar with android's own icons.

To use them you can put them among your resources and use them just like you would do with other resources, images and icons.